# Google Sheets problem duplicating cell formulas with script function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am performing several processes, including copying of information between sheets upon checkbox trigger, and simultaneously duplicating a range of formulas that will continue to copied downwards as more data is moved here. I've successfully completed the first transfer across sheets, but am pulling my hair out to copy formulas in the same sheet. Because I have used lastRow() in the first function, I'm using a slightly different method for plucking out the formulas without success.

As you may see I'm fresh to this type of programming, but ultimately my aim is for this script to be structurally robust enough to handle multiple checkboxes at the same time while alse including conditional formatting.

### Thanks in advance for any and all advice, and here is my code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
// goal to send data from cell in sheet 'staticData'
// to another cell in sheet 'DiscoveryRanking'
// upon checking of checkbox
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r = ss.getActiveRange();
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

if (s.getName() == "staticData" && r.getColumn() == 53 && r.getValue() == true) {
// Create the record in "DiscoveryRanking"
    var prop = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DiscoveryRanking");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 2);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).copyTo(target, { contentsOnly: true });

//the second aim is to copy down a template range with formulas in 'DiscoveryRanking'
//to the line under the retrieved cell data from 'staticData'
//THIS PART IS WHERE I'M HAVING A PROBLEM
    e.ss.getSheetName() == "DiscoveryRanking" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 1 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 27 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 15 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 16 

  var source = ss.getSheetByName("DiscoveryRanking");
  var data_cellRows = e.range.rowStart;     
  source.getRange(data_cellRow,1, 2, 27).getFormulaR1C1();      

  var input = data_cellRows.getRange(data_cellRow.gestLastRow(),1);
  data_cellRows.copyTo(input, setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas));
  }
}
```

***UPDATED: as mentioned in the comments***

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r = ss.getActiveRange();
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

if (s.getName() == "staticData" && r.getColumn() == 53 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var prop = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DiscoveryRanking");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+2, 2);
      Logger.log(target.getValue());
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).copyTo(target, { contentsOnly: true });

    var source =      
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DiscoveryRanking");
    var dataToCopyFormulas = source.getRange('A15:Y15')
    var copyToSheet = ss.getSheetByName ("DiscoveryRanking");

    var sourceValueFormulas = dataToCopyFormulas.getFormulas();
    var lastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow();

    copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, sourceValueFormulas.length, 
    sourceValueFormulas[0].length).setFormulas(sourceValueFormulas);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an `if` missing in your code here? That guard is kind of lost it seems.

Comment: I don't believe so. I would ideally run both these tasks 'if' the checkbox is used.

Comment: I think I should also just specify that I went away from using a normal getRange() function in the second part, primarily due to frustration with not getting the formulas, but only have the cell formatting being copied in a previous iteration.

Comment: I am stil tinkering. This will copies the formulas, but the cell ID's in the formulas no not change according to the new position, which I'd like for them to do.

Comment: So the formulas are being copied but referring to the old cells? Is that correct? Could you maybe provide a sample sheet to reproduce this behavior?